# replace/transform elements of a rdd

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, transformation

I am new to Apache spark and I have a question.

If the elements of a rdd are `rdd=[0.0, 1.49, 2.48, 2.72, 2.45]`, how can I transform this rdd such that all values less than 2 get transformed -1 and rest to 0?
i.e `rdd_transformed=[-1,-1,0,0,0]`

I tried the following, but I fear I didn't get the syntax right.

```
b=2
rdd.map(lambda a: (a,b)).reduce(lambda a,b: -1 if (a<b) else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question (hopefully), try something like:

```
rdd.map(lambda a: -1 if a < 2 else 0)
```